# Running PowerShell code in powershell works, executing as .ps1 doesn't

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I wrote some code which tries to Get a value from one Rest API and post it to another.
I have the code saves in a .ps1 file. If I edit it and run it (or just copy and paste it into an empty PowerShell terminal) it does what I expect. However when I try to run the same .ps1 file directly I get an error on the 2nd Invoke-RestMethod.

Don't understand why I'm getting a different result and the error message not giving me many clues.

What am I doing wrong?

The code I am using is (with modified API key):

```
$encoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($APIkey+":"))
$headers = @{"Content-Type" = "application/json"; "AUTHORIZATION" = "Basic $encoded"}
$APIkey = "123456789"
$metricId = "123"

$r = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://coinbase.com/api/v1/currencies/exchange_rates
$metric = [PSCustomObject]@{
    value = [Math]::Round($r.btc_to_eur, 2)
}

$baseuri = "https://api.numerousapp.com/v1/metrics/$metricId/events"
$data = ConvertTo-Json $metric
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseuri -Body $data -Headers $headers -Method Post
```

And the error message I get when running the .ps1 file is:

`Invoke-RestMethod : :
At C:\NumerousBitcoinEur.ps1:13 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseuri -Body $data -Headers $headers -Method Post
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand`

I'm using PowerShell 4.0

Comment: well I get the same error as you when pasting in the console or when running from ISE. So I don't think the ps1 file as anything to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$APIkey` is being set *after* it is being used, which must be wrong. It probably works in the console because `$APIkey` happens to already be set.

If you like (I think it's a good idea), you can add the following to the top of your scripts to catch errors like this one.

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're absolutely right, that was the problem and it worked in console because it was indeed already set. I tried a total clean restart of console and got the same problem when manually running. Can't believe the problem was that silly!

Thanks for the tip with 'Set-StrictMode -Version Latest', didn't know about that one and looks very helpful.